# background image does not fill the full div size

Tags: css

Here is the css being applied to the div:

```
#header{
    background-size: 100%;
    background: url('../img/header.png');
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #b2d234;
}
```

as you can see in the picture [image: picture], the bottom border fits the whole width, but the background image does not fill neither the full width nor the height, even though there is no padding or margins applied.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Update:

I have zoomed out and so the problem is easily seen. The problem is that the background image is being repeated and there are small spaces between each repetition. I have tried no-repeat option, but then i get the background only once and it does not fill the whole screen.

Please, take a look at the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Updated CSS.

```
#header{
    background-size: cover;
    background: url('../img/header.png');
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #b2d234;
}
```

Comment: Also, if you need a little bleed on your backgrounds just make it background-size:105% and add background-position:center;

Comment: Actually nothing changes with the background size to cover. In fact, if I test it on a much bigger screen I even get the same bleed on the right side. And what I need is the picture to cover the whole width and 200px from the top in height.

Comment: background-position: center; has just removed the top bleed, and made the side ones smaller, but there are still around 7px left from the sides.

Comment: I have editted the question and added one more screenshot, it may be clearer now.